# Google App Indexing: GSDDeepLink call causes build to fail

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, cocoapods

I'm trying to set up my app for Google App Indexing, following Google's instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/ios/app#handle-incoming-urls-that-use-custom-schemes). As soon as I implemented the GSDDeepLink call in my AppDelegate, I get this error when I try to build:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GSDDeepLink", referenced from:
      type metadata accessor for ObjectiveC.GSDDeepLink in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

When I comment out my GSDDeepLink call, it builds. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

try change your values in Build Settings->Linking->Other Linker Flags to this.

$(inherited)

-ObjC

-framework

"CoreText"

"GoogleAppIndexing"